# Как остановить курсор на БЭМ элементе при нажатий ctrl+влево (block__element, block__'курсор'element) в VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Как остановить курсор на БЭМ элементе при нажатий ctrl+влево (block__element, block__'курсор'element) в VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону настройки `editor.wordSeparators`, там можно добавить "_".

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Галочка слева от вопроса)